# Remove Folders from DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, cmd, ddms

I need to remove a particular folder from the `/mnt/sdcard/new`.

I am looking at the folder with the DDMS in Eclipse.

How do we remove a particular folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea then what is the problem, are you able to see the folder inside DDMS ?? If yes you can select and delete it else if you want to do it programmatically then let me know

Comment: You can Delete files but not the Folder by that way @Arfin

Comment: You can't from DDMS, You have to do it by adb shell or programatically, **adb shell rmdir /mnt/sdcard/Folder**

Comment: ohhh yea @Androider you are right .. sorry.

Comment: @Arfin No srry vrry yar..!!You tried is your achievement..!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
C:\>adb shell
$ rmdir /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/mydirectory/
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `rm` command with `-r` parameter to delete a nonempty folder.

```
C:\> adb shell
$ rm -r /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/mydirectory/
```

NOTE: `rmdir` can delete only a nonempty folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below method for delete folder from sdcard

```
// Deletes all files and subdirectories under dir.
// Returns true if all deletions were successful.
// If a deletion fails, the method stops attempting to delete and returns false.
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it
    return dir.delete();
}
```

write below code for call deleteDir() method

```
// Delete an empty directory
boolean success = (new File("directorypath")).delete();
if (!success) {
    // Deletion failed Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean success = (
new File("/data/data/yourpackege/New Folder")).delete();

if (!success) {
         // Deletion failed Message
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not deleted : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}else{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  deleted : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete any folder from ddms first you have to go to adb shell through cmd
simple go to the path where your sdk\platform-tools\ is located ,there is your adb shell

to run command for deleting folders you must first root your device by simply typing

```
adb root
```

then you can delete the folder using

```
rmdir /mnt/sdcard/folder
```

to delete folder with files

```
rm -r /mnt/sdcard/folder
```

hope my answer will help anyone(beginners)